# How can I remove a specific number from a string?

Tags: python

here is the code:

```
aList = ['0.01', 'xyz', 'J0.01', 'abc', 'xyz'];
aList.remove('0.01');
print("List : ", aList)
```

here is the output:
List :

```
['xyz', 'J0.01', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

How can I remove the 0.01 attached to 'J0.01'? I would like to keep the J. Thanks for your time! =)

Comment: sounds like a job for regex

Comment: You're using the list method `remove`. You want a string method instead

Comment: Thanks for the advice good sir! It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want

```
aList = ['0.01', 'xyz', 'J0.01', 'abc', 'xyz'];
>>> [z.replace('0.01', '') for z in aList]

['', 'xyz', 'J', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

If you want to remove also empty strings/whitespaces,

```
>>> [z.replace('0.01', '') for z in aList if z.replace('0.01', '').strip()]
['xyz', 'J', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: I assumed, incorrectly apparently, that he was looking for a generic solution to removing any number from any string.

Comment: @SuperStew Oh I see. It was kind of hard to understand I agree :) Jake Glad I could help

Comment: @SuperStew... I am trying to remove 0.01 attached to every name in a list. I should have been more clear. My apologies for any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re` module:

```
import re

aList = ['0.01', 'xyz', 'J0.01', 'abc', 'xyz'];    
print([i for i in (re.sub(r'\d+\.?\d*$', '', i) for i in aList) if i])
```

Prints:

```
['xyz', 'J', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

EDIT:

The regexp substitution `re.sub(r'\d+\.?\d*$', '', i)` will substitute every digit followed by dot (optional) and followed by any number of digits for empty string. The `$` signifies that the digit should be at the end of the string.

So. e.g. the following matches are valid: `"0.01"`, `"0."`, `"0"`. Explanation on [external site here](https://regex101.com/r/MPR0Ic/1).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This code worked great! =)

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to the complicated expression in your `print` command in the interest of those who are new to `re` which includes me

Comment: Great, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that can works:

```
l = ['0.01', 'xyz', 'J0.01', 'abc', 'xyz']
string = '0.01'
result = []
for x in l :
    if string in x:
        substring = x.replace(string,'')
        if substring != "":
            result.append(substring)
    else:
        result.append(x)

print(result)
```

try it, regards.

Comment: … I have a list of names with 0.01 attached to each of them. For example: Obama, Barak0.01; Trump, Don0.01; etc. When I tried using the code you suggested it only printed the last name in the list (i.e. Trump, Don). Any idea how I could use this code to remove the 0.01 from everyone in the list? This code worked as you stated. I am just new and could use some pointers. Thanks for you time! =)